# Redirect to another view using Ajax in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Javascript. I need help in the following scenario:

I have 2 dropdowns in my view, and a Anchor(a) element. On click of this anchor element, I want to redirect to another view(basically have to call another action function), but I need to pass the current values which are being selected in those 2 drop downs. In short, I need to call another action function and pass the 2 current values selected in drop downs with it.

I have written the following Ajax code, however it is always going to the error part:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: Url.Action("ActionMethod", "MyController"),
    data: {
        param1: DD1Value,
        param2: DD2Value,
        param3: xyz
    },
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = data.redirecturl;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error happened');
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionMethod(DateTime param1, DateTime param2, string param3)
{
//Do some work
//Return View
}
```

Edit:
I do understand the whole point of Ajax is to stay on the same page. I have tried using window.location.href too,:

```
window.location.href = "/MyController/ActionMethod?param1=" + DD1Value+ "&param2=" + DD2Value+ "&param3=" + "xyz"
```

however this is resulting a routing error. Route.config cannot be changed to accommodate this.

Comment: why use ajax when you are redirecting lol?

Comment: @madalinivascu - How else can it be redirected? Sorry I am new to JS

Comment: @NehalJain do a get request

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page. Redirecting is pointless.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yes I do get that. I was trying to use windows.location.href instead, however I need to pass 6 parameters along. Route config cant be changed to accommodate this. How else can parameters be passed along with this?

Comment: The just post your form and in the method use `RedirectToAction()`, but its unclear what you really want to actually do.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the DropDownList values to the Controller bu using the Ajax call shown below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".SelectedCustomer").change(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "MyController")',
                data: { 
                          param1: $('#DD1').val(),
                          param2: $('#DD2').val(),
                          param3: xyz
                          /* add other additional parameters */ },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    SetData(data);
                },
                error: function (data) { onError(data); }
            });
        });
     
    });

</script>
```